# Cannot add email attachment on iOS in .NET Maui

Tags: ios, email, outlook, maui

I am trying to add an email attachment to an email message within my .NET Maui app. However, when trying to do this the attachment is left out without any error raised.

The file being attached exists and the mechanism works well on Android. But on iOS it moves onto Outlook and leaves out the attachment. The file being attached is a JSON file and I don't think there is any issue with attaching JSON files to emails.

Here is my code:

```
var email = new EmailMessage();
email.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(filePath));
email.Subject = Subject;
email.To.Add("some email address here");
await Email.Default.ComposeAsync(email);
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: From the docs “ Some mail clients may restrict the types of files you send, or possibly prevent attachments altogether.”

Comment: I have tried manually creating an email with a JSON file attachment and it works on Outlook within iOS fine. I don't think it's because of a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `EmailAttachment` [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.communication.emailattachment.-ctor?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-applicationmodel-communication-emailattachment-ctor(system-string-system-string)) that has a `string contentType` parameter and pass `"text/plain"` (for your JSON file).

```cs
email.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(filePath, contentType: "text/plain"));
```

In the case of non-JSON attachments, choose the more appropriate content type (MIME type) based on the file. Here's a list of common MIME types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: Good idea however no joy. I've actually updated my code to send a zip file. Using the application/zip MIME type has no effect I still get the same result - no attachment.

Comment: If the same API works fine on Android, but not on iOS, it could be a bug that you could report on the [MAUI repository](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). Also, is this specific to Outlook on iOS? Does it work with Apple's Mail application?

Comment: I tested it on another iOS device that only has the mail app and not outlook. It worked. Seems to be an issue with outlook on iOS.